# journalctl - remove logs of a specific unit

Tags: systemd

With journalctl, it is possible to remove the old logs, by specifying either the maximum disk space they can use, or the maximum age they can have, or the maximum number of separate journal files (using the options `--vacuum-size`, `--vacuum-time` or `--vacuum-files`).

Is there a way to restrain this deletion to a specific systemd unit ?

`journalctl -u <unit> --vacuum-time=2d` seems not to work as desired: according to the documentation, `-u` only works when displaying logs.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

After some research I found that you can't delete logs for a specific `systemd` unit, because the logs are interlaced and if you delete only one unit you'll corrupt the logs, so `journalctl` doesn't let you.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that one *must* use `journalctl` to manipulate `systemd`'s logs… and that `journalctl` itself is not able to do the stuff…

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272662/how-do-i-clear-journalctl-entries-for-a-specific-unit-only/

Comment: That's a major shortcoming. I accidentally wrote some information to the log that should not have been exposed. I wanted to delete only my unit's logs. My only recourse was to delete everyone else's logs, too. journalctl needs to add support for -u unit-name when used with --vacuum-x ....

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the specific version it became possible, [journaltcl documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html) doesn't even mention that `--vacuum-time` (or -size or -files) can be combined with `--unit` but I have ver:249, the vacuuming came in ver:218, and unit filter came in ver:195.

TLDR: Accepted answer is no longer correct. to clean up all logs for a unit:
`journalctl --vacuum-time=1s --unit=your.service`

If you don't mind rotating logs of everything else AND you still find logs from your unit (meaning its last log haven't rotated yet) you can rotate in one go:
`journalctl --rotate --vacuum-time=1s --unit=your.service`

Comment: I probably had version 229 in april 2016. I had also these flags. `--vacuum-*` & `--unit` does not combine: `--unit` is a display-only filter. **If you run your command, you will delete almost your logs**.